# Can you explain the Black-Scholes fair option equation with RND?

Tags: option-pricing, black-scholes, risk-neutral-measure

I am trying to learn Black-Scholes risk-neutral densities with only prior knowledge of fundamental B-S equations (not the derivation). Sorry if this was asked already or if I sound completely clueless.

Basically I do not understand what lowercase ***x*** stands for in the integral formula below. It is then subsequently used for the lognormal density. X stands for exercise price of a European call option as usual.

"Let [image: formula1] denote the risk-neutral density of [image: formula2]. Then

[image: formula]

If you have any recommendations on sources to read about this more thoroughly, feel free to link them, thanks.

Comment: Formally $x$ is the integration variable, which starts at $x=X$ and ends at $x=\infty$. The integral represents the *area* under the curve $(x-X)f_Q(x)$ as $x$ varies over this range. $f_Q$ represents the lognormal density.

Comment: In financial terms $x$ represents all the possible stock price values at time $T$ that have a positive call option payoff (i.e $x\equiv S_T>=X$)

Comment: @noob2 thank you very much for confirmation!

Comment: Yeah, if the person who wrote this equation had used a consistent symbol (either $x$ or $S_T$) on both sides of the equal sign instead of mixing them it would have avoided misunderstanding.